# BCP utility SQL Server Export to CSV - destination CSV file never gets created

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv, bcp

I'm experiencing the following error when using the `bcp` utility in SQL Server 2017.

I need to export data from a view in SQL Server to a `.CSV` file using a comma as the column delimiter. My data contains comma in certain columns. So I used " as a column qualifier when created a view using `[+'"' column_name + '"']`.

I tried 3 different ways:

**Option 1:**

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable
          WHERE Rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100 ORDER BY Rn"
       queryout "E:\MyFolder\MyFileName.txt" -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

**Option 2:**

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable
          WHERE Rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100 ORDER BY Rn"
       queryout "E:\MyFolder\MyFileName.txt" -c -t, [MyServer_Name] -T -S'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

**Option 3**

```
   declare @sql varchar(8000)
   select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable
              WHERE Rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100 ORDER BY Rn"
           queryout "E:\MyFolder\MyFileName.txt" -c -t, [MyServer_Name] -T -S ' + '@@servername' 
   exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

In every case I'm getting the same output but the CSV file never gets created:

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]  [-l login timeout]
  NULL
```

**PS**: I found alternative solution to import data into `.CSV` from SQL Server. But the problem here is that `sqlcmd` - unlike `bcp` - does not accept two characters as text qualifier. I decided to use a text qualifier of 2 chars `~^` following comma as a field separator.

```
 exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s -W -Q "set nocount on;select * from MyTable" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "E:\MyFile.csv"'
```

> where `-s` is col_separator
>
> Specifies the column-separator character. The default is a blank space. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDCOLSEP. To use characters that have special meaning to the operating system such as the ampersand (&), or semicolon (;), enclose the character in quotation marks ("). The column separator can be any 8-bit character.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15 )

Comment: Why do you need to use a comma as a delimiter? It's the worst possible delimiter. Anyway if that's the output you;re getting (BCP help), then it would appear the BCP command is not built correctly

Comment: Is the formatting of code in the question representative of the actual code formatting in SQL Server? If that's the case - you can't break up command lines over multiple lines like that. `bcp "select * from MyDB.dbo.MyTable` is not a valid command.

Comment: If you are using this to transfer data between SQL Servers, _forget_ about delimiters. Use native format `-n` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command lines supplied to `xp_cmdshell` cannot span multiple lines of text, they need to be specified completely on a single line. Try building the command as a series of concatenated strings like this:

```sql
declare @sql varchar(8000) =
    'bcp' +
    ' "select * from MyDB.dbo.MyTable WHERE Rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100 order by Rn"' +
    ' queryout' +
    ' "E:\MyFolder\MyFileName.txt"' +
    ' -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

When concatenating the strings be mindful of where you need to include white space between each segment so that command line parameters don't run into each other.

Comment: What parameter do I need specify to allow bcp to include header in the flat file when reading from a SLQ Server?

Comment: I found alternative solution exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s -W -Q "set nocount on;select * from MyTable" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "E:\MyFile.csv"' The problem is that sqlcmd unlike bcp does not except to characters as a text qualifier. I decided to use a text qualifier of 2 chars ~^ following comma as a filed separator.

Answer (score 0):

P.S.

I found alternative solution to Import data into CSV fro SQL Server. But the problem here is that sqlcmd unlike bcp does not except to characters as a text qualifier. I decided to use a text qualifier of 2 chars ~^ following comma as a filed separator.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s -W -Q "set nocount on;select * from MyTable" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "E:\MyFile.csv"'
```

Where -s is col_separator Specifies the column-separator character. The default is a blank space. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDCOLSEP. To use characters that have special meaning to the operating system such as the ampersand (&), or semicolon (;), enclose the character in quotation marks ("). The column separator can be any 8-bit character.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15 )

Also we have another alternative solution that includes headers, but there you have no control on how you pass your query.

```
set BCP_EXPORT_SERVER=YourServerName
set BCP_EXPORT_DB=YourDBName
set BCP_EXPORT_TABLE=YourTableName

BCP "DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);SELECT @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + ',', '') + column_name from %BCP_EXPORT_DB%.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='%BCP_EXPORT_TABLE%'; select @colnames;" queryout HeadersOnly.csv -c -t, -T -S%BCP_EXPORT_SERVER%
BCP %BCP_EXPORT_DB%.dbo.%BCP_EXPORT_TABLE% out TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv -c -t"|", -T -S%BCP_EXPORT_SERVER%

set BCP_EXPORT_SERVER=
set BCP_EXPORT_DB=
set BCP_EXPORT_TABLE=

copy /b HeadersOnly.csv+TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv TableData.csv

del HeadersOnly.csv
del TableDataWithoutHeaders.csv
```

Comment: If you are using this to transfer data between SQL Servers, _forget_ about delimiters. Use native format `-n` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15